# Executing more than one service in Android

Tags: android, service

I have faced this question in one Interview.

**What will happen when we startService() more than once before previous service was not closed?**

```
public void start(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    startService(i);

}
public void stop(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    stopService(i);

}
public void startAnother1(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    startService(i);
}
```

**A new Service creates and executes in main Thread.But where it will executes? Whether it will wait for finishing of first service or it will execute separately and parallel in same main thread?**

If i write **startAnother1** as below what will happen

```
public void startAnother1(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MyAnotherService.class);
        startService(i);
    }
```

And starting this service before first service was not complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What will happen when we startService() more than once before previous
>   service was not closed?

`onStartCommand()` will be called. The `Service` will go through its lifecycle. This means you will have two `Services` running at the same time.

> A new Service creates and executes in main Thread.But where it will
>   executes? Whether it will wait for finishing of first service or it
>   will execute separately and parallel in same main thread?

I think here you meant to say: "When will it execute?". When you call `Context.startService()`, Android will call `onStartCommand()` (the `Service` is already running so no need to call `onCreate()`) and the `Service` lifecycle will begin. That is, you will have two services running until you call `stopSelf()` or `Context.stopService()`. `Services` are always ran on the UI `Thread` by default. If you want a `Service` implementation that runs on its own `Thread` use `IntentService`.

Comment: So, both are executes parallel ?

Comment: Yes, you will have two instances of your `Service` running.

Answer (score 0):

If service is not currently running then `onCreate()` and `onStartCommand()` will be called. 
But if service is alive then just `onStartCommand()` will be called.